# IIS 8 Access Denied to Stop App Pools

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

I have an application that deploys code to various target servers. Recently Windows 2012 servers have been added as target servers but the application's agent service returns an 'Access denied' message when trying to perform any tasks linked to IIS. For example the application will try to Stop the relevant App Pools and Sites before copying the code to the target. First thing the App does when trying to stop the App Pool is determine which app pool needs to be stopped:

```
private DirectoryEntry FindSite(int nPort)
    {
        using (DirectoryEntry sites = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format(m_adSitesPath, m_RemoteServerName)))
        {
            sites.RefreshCache();

            foreach (DirectoryEntry de in sites.Children)
            {
                de.RefreshCache();
                if (de.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebServer")
                {
                    string port = GetNullableDirMultiValuePart(de, "ServerBindings", 0, 1);
                    if (nPort == int.Parse(port))
                    {
                        return de; 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

App fails after using (DirectoryEntry sites... with Access Denied. 
On the actual server the ID the Agent is logged in as is in the Admin group and has the Log on as a Service privilege set. 
This application does not display this issue when running on Windows 2008 servers with IIS7.
Has anyone any advice on where I could start investigating? It appears to be permissions related but the ID setup matches on both servers so is there something with IIS8 that I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: Have you enabled IIS 6 Compatibility role service?

Comment: I'll work with my colleague who manages the servers to try this - thank you!

Comment: another hint for you is that if you are managing only IIS 7 and above, it is time to switch to Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll.

Comment: We've tried enabling the IIS 6 Compatibility role service - but still getting the Access Denied message. Without having to rewrite the methods are there any other IIS settings that need to be enabled/disabled?

Comment: My application target service is deployed across a mixture of 2008 and 2012 servers, and the version of Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll is different on both. I tried building my application with the MWA v8.5 DLL but when I deploy the code to the 2008 server the Service doesn't do anything. due to the MWA.dll version being different on a 2008 server.

Comment: At present our applications Service is using the DirectoryEntry class to try and manipulate IIS. Should I still be able to use the properties from this class to work with IIS 8/Server 2012 and stop/start app pools for example? Are there any known issues of using the DirectoryEntry class to stop/start app pools in IIS8/Server 2012?